# Why is Mockito behaving weird with InputStreams?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, stubbing

While debugging I came across something incredibly strange using Mockito 1.10. I was hoping someone could explain the behavior perceived here:

When I run the following, my thread hangs and my test never returns. CPU of the Java process created goes astronomical too!

```
@Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void mockitoWeirdness() throws IOException {
    final InputStream mis = mock(InputStream.class);
    doThrow(IOException.class).when(mis).read();
    ByteStreams.copy(mis, new ByteArrayOutputStream());
}
```

When I manually stub this method as follows, the expected IOException is thrown:

```
@Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void nonMockitoExpected() throws IOException {
    final InputStream mis = new InputStream() {

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException();
        }
    };
    ByteStreams.copy(mis, new ByteArrayOutputStream());
}
```

Any help understanding how and why the mockito method is failing would be fantastic.

Comment: I do not know `ByteStreams.copy` implementation but maybe it is not calling `read()` which reads one byte but rather calls `read(byte[])`

Comment: I suspect that `ByteStreams.copy()` calls something else on the InputStream before the read(). Would be quite helpful if we had this class' code in order to investigate further.

Comment: ByteStreams is the GoogleGuava library for this. I think you are both correct here. When I spy the class, the behavior succeeds. Will do some more investigation as to what method this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [ByteStreams](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/5b608043b9d56a4427a2d8c1583f6f3c5a4e1023/guava/src/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.java) implementation, you can see that the **read(buf)** method is used.
In your case it returns **null** because there is no mock definition for it and this causes an endless loop in the *copy* method.

You may either change the [default mock behaviour](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock(java.lang.Class,%20org.mockito.stubbing.Answer)) or manually add a definition for the *read(buff)* method.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to set up your mock to call the real methods of `InputStream` when you haven't stubbed them

```
final InputStream mis = Mockito.mock(InputStream.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
```

The [javadoc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#CALLS_REAL_METHODS) states

> This implementation can be helpful when working with legacy code. When
>   this implementation is used, **unstubbed methods will delegate to the
>   real implementation. This is a way to create a partial mock object
>   that calls real methods by default.**

Mockito, by default, mocks everything. The [`ByteStreams#copy`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.java#L101) method you used first invokes `InputStream#read(byte[])`. Since mockito has mocked it, it will return 0 which `ByteStreams#copy` interprets as "there is more to read from this stream" and keeps reading (infinite loop).

By using `Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS`, you're telling Mockito to call the actual implementation in `InputStream`, which will delegate to `read()`, which you've stubbed to throw an exception.